# Basis for a vectorspace

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm studying Linear Algebra, and I have a question to the following exercise.

Let $U$ be a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$, such $\text{dim}(U)=2$. Now I have to show that there exists $u_1,u_2\in \mathbb{R}^3$ such that $(u_1,u_2)$ is a basis for $U$.

I'm not sure how I'm suppose to show this, since it seems obvious to me. I mean if $U$ has dimension 2, then it means it is spanned by 2 vectors?

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong or what I should try to do?

Comment: are you sure this is written as you said?

Answer (score 0):

It can be spanned by two vectors and *no less*.

Actually one shows that for a vector space $E$ that can be generated by a finite number of vectors, the following two numbers are equal:

1. The *minimal number* of vectors that can span $E$;
2. The *maximal number* of vectors that are linearly independent.

It is this number that is called the dimension of $E$.

Comment: condition $\text{dim}(U)=2$ implies that $U$ is spanned by two independent vectors from $\mathbb{R}^3$. Task is to show them.

Comment: No. Task is to show they exist, unless the O.P. transcribed the question approximately. With $\dim U=2$ as the only information, you can do no more.

Comment: The condition given, $\text{dim}(U)=2$, implies they exist

Comment: So the question is not complete.